# iPhone Cocos2d Game Menu Text Entry or Text Field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Working on my third *Cocos2d* iPhone game and running into problems trying to make a create new account textfield. I have a menu image and some text that need to be displayed. On top of this layer I would like a *Textfield* so that the user can type the name of their new account. Seems like it would be pretty simple. I have looked at every example I could find online and nothing seems to work. Here is the method that I need to create the textfield in:

```
-(void) CreateNewAccount: (id) sender
{
[self removeChild:MainMenu cleanup:YES];
BG2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"WelcomeMenu.png"];
BG2.position = ccp(512, 384);
[self addChild:BG2 z:6];
[self removeChild:BG cleanup:YES];
NewNameText = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"NewName.png"];
NewNameText.position = ccp(512, 300);
[self addChild:NewNameText z:7];     
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your text field is actually a sprite?  I would suggest creating an actual UITextField for your purposes.

See the following: [UITextField Example in Cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693483/textfield-example-in-cocos2d)

Comment: No, the text sprite is just a description explaining what to do. It is unrelated to the UITextField... And I have tried it but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Following the examples in the link that I posted, where does it fall short?