# Call a function in AppDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Following the solution (the highest-voted answer actually) at [UITextField Example in Cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693483/textfield-example-in-cocos2d), I managed to do it except the line

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] specifyStartLevel];
```

I have placed it in my scene, I get this warning:

> **Instance method '-specifyStartLevel' not found (return type defaults to 'id')**

Why is that? I clearly have `-specifyStartLevel` defined in the header and implementation of my AppDelegate...

---

**Edit**: Declaration of *specifyStartLevel*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class RootViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UIWindow            *window;
    UITextField *levelEntryTextField;
    RootViewController  *viewController;
}
- (void)specifyStartLevel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

And implementation:

```
- (void)specifyStartLevel
{
    [levelEntryTextField setText:@""];
    [window addSubview:levelEntryTextField];
    [levelEntryTextField becomeFirstResponder];    
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code of the declaration of specifyStartLevel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Right now, your class doesn't know anything about your delegate's methods.  You need to import your delegate into your implementation, not your interface (to avoid cycled imports).

For example,

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Then you should cast the returned delegate in your nested method call to be your delegate type.  For example:

```
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] specifyStartLevel];
```

Comment: Thanks - no more warnings. However, the keyboard does not appear when I call it from the scene. Yet, if I call the function right inside the AppDelegate, it does. Got ideas?

Comment: That's odd.  Please either set a breakpoint or put a log inside the `specifyStartLevel` function to see if it is even run when called from within your subclass.

Comment: It seems it is being called after all. However, the keyboard doesn't seem visible at all.

Comment: Well that's odd.  I'd just create a new question here on SO with your problem instead of trying to figure it out here.

Comment: Ah! I was creating the UITextField *after* running the scene. And the scene was trying to open the keyboard from the init method... Thank you sir.

Comment: Glad you fixed it!  Best of luck on your project. :)

Comment: One little question: how can I change it so it is landscape instead of portrait?

Comment: Change what so it's portrait?  The app?  You can do that in your Xcode project settings.

Comment: I mean the UITextField itself. You see, my game is landscape, but for some reason the above code gives me a textfield with portrait-like orientation (I write vertically).

Comment: Whoops, looks like I didn't see your question. Perhaps that'd be better answered in a new question.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add your method in `AppDelegate.h` file such as:

   ```
   - (void)Welcome
   ```
2. Implement the method in `AppDelegate.m` file such as:

   ```
    - (void)Welcome
    {
        NSLog(@"Welcome")

    }
   ```
3. Set the `UIApplication` delegate in method such as:

   ```
   AppDelegate *appDelegate=[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   [appDelegate Welcome];
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the AppDelegate into the .m file where you use

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] specifyStartLevel];
```

I like to import it with a header that gives me a shortcut.

```
GlobalData.h

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#define APPDELEGATE (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

Then when I use it in any class I just

```
#import "GlobalData.h"

// to gain access to the delegate
AppDelegate * appDelegate = APPDELEGATE;
```

I use this approach because I can then store more #define's to some global constants
(ie soundFXVolume - `#define SOUND_FX_V 0.6`)

Comment: +1 for the macro.  Normally I'd say they're evil, but in this case it's useful.

Answer (score 3):

`-[UIApplication delegate]` returns an object of type `id<UIApplicationDelegate>`, so the compiler only knows the methods that objects of that type respond to, even thought your custom delegate responds to `specifyStartLevel`. You can either ignore the warning, or cast the return value of `-[UIApplication delegate]`:

```
[(YourCustomAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] specifyStartLevel];
```

Comment: Casting would be preferred over ignoring the warning. Warnings are called warnings for a reason and it can lead to subtle bugs if you get into the bad habit of ignoring them.

Comment: @Paul.s: True, but in this case, it's definitely safe to ignore.

Comment: yup it is totally innocent until you change the method signature and forget to update elsewhere in code. If you had removed the original warning you would then get a nice new one telling you about this. If I had my way I would always compile with `-Werror`

Comment: @Paul.s: One of the drawbacks of working with a dynamically-typed language. Unit tests should practically prevent such errors. But, you can cast if you're so inclined, so best of both worlds.