# How can i use the string declared in appDelegate in my ViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

Suppose i have declared the NSString in appDelegate and i want to use that string in my ViewController. How can i use that string in my ViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((appDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).myString;
```

Answer (score 3):

For just a string, many people will recommend NSUserDefaults.

If you want to use the AppDelegate, the answer overlaps this question [Call a function in AppDelegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233253/call-a-function-in-appdelegate/)

Here is my answer

You can create a header file that has a macro to the AppDelegate

```
GlobalData.h

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#define APPDELEGATE (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

Then use it in any class

```
#import "GlobalData.h"

// to gain access to the delegate
AppDelegate * appDelegate = APPDELEGATE;
```

To access your string (assume it is a property called globalString)

```
appDelegate.globalString;
```

I use this approach because I can then store more #define's to some global constants
(ie soundFXVolume - `#define SOUND_FX_V 0.6`)