# How to call a method from appdelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification

I have a switch statement that utilizes the nsuserdefaults bool function to determine on and off.My problem is how do I call the appdelegate.m method in view controller when switch key bool is yes. Basically calling the appdelagte.m method inside of the first if statement in view controller.m.

Appdelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
     TUPushHelper * helper = [[TUPushHelper alloc] initWithTokenData:devToken];
     [helper registerDevice];
}
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SwitchKey"]) {
    NSLog(@"ok");   
}
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SwitchKey"]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]unregisterForRemoteNotifications];   
}
```

Comment: found another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233253/call-a-function-in-appdelegate?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bool isOn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SwitchKey"];

if (isOn) {
    NSLog(@"ok");   
}


if (!isOn) {
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[((AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) someMethod:nil];
```

and don't forget `#import "AppDelegate.h`