# How can I use UITextField in Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uitextfield

I want to use UITextField in Cocos2d, so I wrote the following code:

```
// In HelloWorldLayer...
-(id) init
{
    if( self=[super init] )
    {
        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        UIView *view = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];

        //        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(60.0, 45.0, 360.0, 25.0);
        CGPoint pos1 = ccp( 60.0, winSize.height - 45.0 );
        CGPoint pos2 = ccp( 360.0, 25.0 );

        pos1 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToUI:pos1];
        pos2 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToUI:pos2];

        // UITextField *_tField; it is declared in field
        _tField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(pos1.x, pos1.y, pos2.x, pos2.y)];
        _tField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _tField.borderStyle     = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        _tField.returnKeyType   = UIReturnKeyDone;
        _tField.delegate        = self;

        [view addSubview:_tField];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now I have problem like this:
http://serviceapi.nmv.naver.com/flash/convertIframeTag.nhn?vid=F25D1799886DD32FDA54463C2458197E492A&outKey=V1269fde60a3180c7d50216a83d22b478817df9b6060a511adffa16a83d22b478817d&width=720&height=438

How can I solve this problem...?

Comment: Please add your error message- do not merely add a link as they become outdated.

Comment: But my code is able to be compiled well... Does error message mean the problems, not only the compile errors? Then I got it. (I'm sorry but I'm not good at English well..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the problem, do you mean why the text is not being written horizontally? 
Because the text is actually written horizontally, maybe you have something else that is affecting the code.

Comment: you should check out this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693483/textfield-example-in-cocos2d

Comment: This link is very helpful! I didn't know about CGAffineTransformMakeRotation().. and I solved my problem with this! Thank you :-)