# Textfield in cocos2d/kobold2d not showing color

Tags: colors, cocos2d-iphone, textfield, kobold2d

I need to create a textfield where a player in my game can enter their name for highscore purposes. I followed this question: [UITextField Example in Cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693483/textfield-example-in-cocos2d) , and successfuly created a textfield with the keyboard. However, the textfield's text is white and the background color is also white so I cannot see the textfield, only the keyboard.

Here is the code:

appdelegate.h

```
#import "KKAppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate : KKAppDelegate
{
  UITextField *nameTextField;

}

-(void)specifyPlayerName;

@end
```

appdelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

-(void) initializationComplete
{

#ifdef KK_ARC_ENABLED
CCLOG(@"ARC is enabled");
#else
CCLOG(@"ARC is either not available or not enabled");
#endif
}

 - (void)specifyPlayerName
{
NSLog(@"called");

nameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 165, 200, 90)];
[nameTextField setDelegate:self];
[nameTextField setText:@""];
[nameTextField setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:nameTextField];
[nameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {
//Terminate editing
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*)textField {
if (textField==nameTextField) {
    [nameTextField endEditing:YES];

    // here is where you should do something with the data they entered

    GameData* data = [GameData sharedData];
    data.playerName = nameTextField.text;
    NSLog(@"entered: %@", data.playerName);
}
}
```

The method is being called from another class/button

```
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]performSelector:@selector(specifyPlayerName)];
```

I tried to set the color of the textfield, but it is still showing up as all white. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the textfield was hidden behind the other view, so

```
  [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:nameTextField];
```

instead of

```
[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:nameTextField];
```

The textfield colors are default to be black on white.